# Performance check of unordinary simple JCM structures in minimal i386 BIOS tasks

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, nasm, protected-mode

I'm continuing my investigations into a proof of concept for BIOS 16-32 tasks. Previously my post investigated a regular method for tasking between protected mode and the BIOS and a basic 16 <-> 32 task method found on this link [Proof of Concept for 16 to 32 protected mode BIOS taskings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76011742/proof-of-concept-for-16-to-32-protected-mode-bios-taskings)

Now the most recent tests of my code show a discrepancy between the jmp-if conditions are met structures inside the BIOS task segment.To summarize the test here the problem occurs on the 2nd label of the keyboard input controller code that increments the graphics from the keycodes. However the structure fails on the 2nd labeled instance of the program (SetOn:). This observation can be verified by uncommenting the instanced variables. Like before I'm adding my source code in hopes to clarify such a discrepancy and would be really happy to look into this more.

stage1.asm

```
;    ReTimerOS
;    Copyright (C) 2022,2023  Christopher Hoy
;
;    This file is part of ReTimerOS
;    ReTimerOS is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
;    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
;    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
;    (at your option) any later version.
;
;    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
;    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
;    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
;    GNU General Public License for more details.
;
;    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
;    along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.


;[ORG 0x7E00]

%define BUILD_GDT_DESC(bounds,base,access,flags) \
((( base & 0x00FFFFFF) << 16) | \
(( base & 0xFF000000) << 32) | \
( bounds & 0x0000FFFF) |        \
(( bounds & 0x000F0000) << 32) | \
(( access & 0xFF) << 40) |      \
(( flags & 0x0F) << 52))        

TSS_IO_MAP_SIZE     EQU 0x400/8


%define REBASE_ADDRESS(A)  (0x7E00 + ((A) - BIOS32_PREP))

[BITS 16]

section .data

ROWS    EQU 25
COLS1   EQU 80

section .text

_prep_module2:
;   jmp _prep_module2_

;[bits 32]
BIOS32_PREP:use32
    pusha
    ;pushf
    ; save current esp to edx
    mov edx, esp
    ; jumping to 16 bit protected mode
    ; disable interrupts
    cli
    ; clear cr3 by saving cr3 data in ebx register
    xor ecx, ecx
    mov ebx, cr3
    mov cr3, ecx
    ; load new empty GDT
    lgdt [REBASE_ADDRESS(bios32_gdt_ptr)]
;    lgdt [REBASE_ADDRESS(gdt32Ptr)]
    ; load new empty IDT
    lidt [REBASE_ADDRESS(bios32_idt_ptr)]
    ; jump to 16 bit protected mode


    jmp 0x30:REBASE_ADDRESS(__protected_mode_16)
;    jmp code16_post:REBASE_ADDRESS(__protected_mode_16)

;[bits 16]
; 16 bit protected mode
__protected_mode_16:use16
    ; jumping to 16 bit real mode
    mov ax, 0x38
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax
    ; turn off protected mode
    ; set bit 0 to 0
    mov eax, cr0
    and al,  ~0x01
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp 0x0:REBASE_ADDRESS(__real_mode_16)

; 16 bit real mode
__real_mode_16:use16
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x8c00
    ; enable bios interrupts to call
    sti
    ; save current context, all general, segment registers, flags
    pusha
    mov cx, ss
    push cx
    mov cx, gs
    push cx
    mov cx, fs
    push cx
    mov cx, es
    push cx
    mov cx, ds
    push cx
    pushf
    ; get current stack pointer & save it to current_esp
    mov ax, sp
    mov edi, current_esp
    stosw
    ; load our custom registers context
    mov esp, REBASE_ADDRESS(bios32_in_reg16_ptr)
    ; only use some general register from the given context
    popa
    ; set a new stack for bios interrupt
    mov sp, 0x9c00
    ; call immediate interrupt opcode to execute context
    pusha
;   mov dx,sp 
;   jmp GraphicCtrlA
    jmp short bios32_GraphicCtrlA



bios32_GraphicCtrlA:
; will be bios interrupt number passed
    ; put the actual interrupt number here
;   db 0xCD
;    db 0x10
;   db 0x01

    mov ax,0x13
    
    int 0x10
;graphic_function2:

;   call bios32_int_number_ptr
    mov dh,1
    mov dl,1
    call GraphicPrint

;   jmp loopstep1
;   popa

;   mov ax,0x13 
;   int 0x10

loopstep1:
    mov ah,01h
    int 16h
    jz loopstep1

    call GraphicPrint

    mov ah,00h
    int 16h

    cmp ah,48h
    jnz SetOn
    cmp dl,0
    jz SetOn
    dec dl

SetOn:

    cmp ah,50h
;   jnz short SetOff
    cmp dl,24
;   jz short SetOff
    inc dl

SetOff:

    cmp ah,48h
;   jnz SetNotLeft
    cmp dh,0
;   jz SetNotLeft
    dec dh  

SetNotLeft:

    cmp ah,4Dh
;   jnz SetNotRight
    cmp dh,39
;   jz SetNotRight
    inc dh  

SetNotRight:

    call GraphicPrint
    jmp loopstep1

    popa

    jmp $   
;   jmp poll_function

GraphicPrint:
    mov cx,0A000h
    mov es,cx
;   mov ax

    push dx

    mov ax,8
    mul dh
    mov bp,ax

    mov ax,8*320
    mov bx,0
    add bl,dl
    mul bx
    add bp,ax

    pop dx

    mov si,GraphicA
    mov cl,8
    
PrintGraphicY:
    push bp

    mov ch,8

PrintGraphicX:
    mov al,[ds:si]
    xor al,[es:bp]
    mov [es:bp],al
    inc si
    inc bp
    dec ch
    jnz PrintGraphicX

    pop bp
    add bp,320
    dec cl
    jnz PrintGraphicY
;   mov sp,dx
;GraphicCtrlRet:
    hlt

;   popa
    ret
;   jmp poll_function
;   jmp GraphicCtrlRet
;   ret

GraphicA:
    db 00h,00h,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,00h,00h  
    db 00h,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,00h
    db 0Eh,0Eh,05h,0Eh,0Eh,05h,0Eh,0Eh
    db 0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh
    db 0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh
    db 0Eh,0Eh,04h,0Eh,0Eh,04h,0Eh,0Eh
    db 00h,0Eh,0Eh,04h,04h,0Eh,0Eh,00h
    db 00h,00h,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,00h,00h




poll_function:
    ; get our output context here
    mov esp, REBASE_ADDRESS(bios32_out_reg16_ptr)
    add sp, 28 ; restore stack used for calling our context
    ; save current context, all general, segment registers, flags
    pushf
    mov cx, ss
    push cx
    mov cx, gs
    push cx
    mov cx, fs
    push cx
    mov cx, es
    push cx
    mov cx, ds
    push cx
    pusha
    ; restore the current_esp to continue
    mov esi, current_esp
    lodsw
    mov sp, ax
    ; restore all current context, all general, segment registers, flags
    popf
    pop cx
    mov ds, cx
    pop cx
    mov es, cx
    pop cx
    mov fs, cx
    pop cx
    mov gs, cx
    pop cx
    mov ss, cx
    popa

;    jmp _prep_module2_
    

    ; jumping to 32 bit protected mode
    ; set bit 0 in cr0 to 1
;testGate:
    lgdt[gdt32Ptr]
;   lgdt [REBASE_ADDRESS(bios32_gdt_ptr)]
    mov eax, cr0
;   inc eax
    or eax,1
    mov cr0, eax
;   smsw eax
;    jmp 0x08:REBASE_ADDRESS(__protected_mode_32)
 ;   jmp 0x10:REBASE_ADDRESS(__protected_mode_32)
        
_prep_module2_:
    cld
    cli

    in al,0x92
    or al,2
    out 0x92,al

;   mov [saved_segment],ds

;   lidt[Idtpipe32]
;   jmp code32_post:REBASE_ADDRESS(__protected_mode_32)
    jmp code32_post:__protected_mode_32

;   jmp 0x08:__protected_mode_32
;   jmp 0x10:__protected_mode_32    
;   jmp 0x08:REBASE_ADDRESS(__protected_mode_32)
;   jmp 0x10:REBASE_ADDRESS(__protected_mode_32)


[bits 32]
; 32 bit protected mode
__protected_mode_32:use32
;    mov ax, 0x10
    mov ax,data32_post
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
;    mov ss, ax
    ; restore cr3
    mov cr3, ebx
    ; restore esp
    mov esp, edx

;    sti
    popa

;   hlt

;   jmp _BIOS32_PREP
;   jmp code16_post:REBASE_ADDRESS(__protected_mode_32)
;use16
;   jmp code16_post:REBASE_ADDRESS(BIOS32_PREP)

;    lgdt [REBASE_ADDRESS(bios32_gdt_ptr)]

 ;   jmp 0x30:REBASE_ADDRESS(__protected_mode_16)

    jmp $

    
.loopcheck:
    hlt
    jmp .loopcheck


__padding:
    db 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 0x0
bios32_gdt_entries:
    ; 8 gdt entries
    resb 64
bios32_gdt_ptr:
    dd 0x00000000
    dd 0x00000000
bios32_idt_ptr:
    dd 0x00000000
    dd 0x00000000
bios32_in_reg16_ptr:
    resw 14
bios32_out_reg16_ptr:
    dd 0xaaaaaaaa
    dd 0xaaaaaaaa
    dd 0xaaaaaaaa
    dd 0xaaaaaaaa
    dd 0xaaaaaaaa
    dd 0xaaaaaaaa
    dd 0xaaaaaaaa
current_esp:
    dw 0x0000




section .data 

gdt32:
    dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(0,0,0,0)
gdt32code:
    dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(0x0000ffff,0,10011010b,1100b)
gdt32data:
    dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(0x0000ffff,0,10010010b,1100b)
gdt16code:
    dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(0x0000ffff,0,10011010b,1000b)
gdt16data:
    dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(0x0000ffff,0,10010010b,1000b)

    ;gdt16tss:dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(0x8230,TSS_SIZE-1,10001001b,0000b) & 0 << 22
gdt32tss:
    dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(TSS_SIZE-1,0x8280,10001001b,0000b)
;   dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(TSS_SIZE-1,0x9260,10001001b,0000b)    
.stub1:

    code32_post: equ gdt32code -gdt32
    data32_post: equ gdt32data -gdt32
;.stub:
    code16_post: equ gdt16code -gdt32
    data16_post: equ gdt16data -gdt32

    tss32_post: equ gdt32tss -gdt32
    
    gdt32Len: equ $-gdt32   
    gdt32Ptr: dw gdt32Len-1
        dd gdt32


align 4
;vidmem_ptr: dd VIDEO_TEXT_ADDR
pm_str: db 'protected mode string ',0
pm_str_length: equ $-pm_str
vm_str: db 'virtual',0
;vidmem_address: dw 0

;resb 512
times 512 db 0

align 16
tss:
.back_link:     dd 0
.esp0:          dd 0
.ss0:           dd 0
.esp1:          dd 0
.ss1:           dd 0
.esp2:          dd 0
.ss2:           dd 0
.cr3:           dd 0
.eip:           dd 0
.eflags:        dd 0
.eax:           dd 0
.ecx:           dd 0
.edx:           dd 0
.ebx:           dd 0
.esp:           dd 0
.ebp:           dd 0
.esi:           dd 0
.type2:         dd 0
.es:            dd 0
.cs:            dd 0
.ss:            dd 0
.ds:            dd 0
.fs:            dd 0
.gs:            dd 0
.ldt:           dd 0
.trap:          dw 0
.iomap_base:    dw 0

.iomap: TIMES TSS_IO_MAP_SIZE db 0x00

%if TSS_IO_MAP_SIZE > 0
.iomap_pad:db 0xff

%endif
.end:
TSS_SIZE: EQU tss.end -tss

align 4

ColorTable: db 00h,01h,02h,03h,04h,05h,06h,07h
            ;db 10h,11h,12h,13h,14h,15h,16h,17h
            db 38h,39h,3Ah,3Bh,3Ch,3Dh,3Eh,3Fh
ColorTableSize: equ $-ColorTable

save_cr0    dd 0
save_cr3    dd 0
saved_segment   resd 0
gate_voucher    dw 1

;X  dd 0
;Y   dd 0
;color_pkg  dw 5

section .bss
align 16 
;ring0_proc_stack: resb RING0_PROC_STACK_SIZE
ring0_proc_stack_placer:

align 4
save_esp:   resd 1
save_ss:    resd 1


;rm_poll_prep:
;   mov cx,gdt16data
;   xor ecx,ecx

;   mov ds,cx
;   mov es,cx
;   mov gs,cx
;   mov fs,cx

;   mov cs,gdt16code
;   mov ds,gdt16data

;   lgdt[gdt16Ptr]
;   lidt[Idtpipe]
;   sti
    
;   jmp $
;   jmp color_function


;._prep_stage:
;   mov dword [tss.ss],VM_STACK_SEG 
;   mov dword [tss.esp],VM_STACK_OFS
;   mov dword [tss.eflags],1 << FLAGS_VM_CMP | 1 << FLAGS_CMP1
;   mov dword [tss.cs],VM_CS_SEG
;   mov dword [tss.eip],vm_module



;prep_stage4:
;   mov si,0
;   mov ds,si
;   push ds
;   push ds
;   push ds
;   push ds 
;   push VM_STACK_SEG
;   push VM_STACK_OFS
;   push dword 1 << FLAGS_VM_CMP
;   push dword 1 << FLAGS_VM_CMP | 1 << FLAGS_CMP1 
;   push dword 1 << FLAGS_VM_CMP | 1 << FLAGS_CMP1 | 2 << FLAGS_CMP_IOPL
;   push dword 1 << FLAGS_VM_CMP | 1 << FLAGS_CMP1 | 2 << FLAGS_CMP_IOPL | 1 << FLAGS_CMP_IF 

;   push VM_CS_SEG
;   push vm_module
;   iret




;poll_function1:
;.prep:

;   xor ebx,ebx
;   xor edx,edx
    
;   mov ax,0

;   mov cx,0

;   mov es,cx
;   mov ax,ROWS
;   mov bx,es:0x044A
;   mul bx
;   add ax,COLS1
;   shl ax,1
;   mov si,ax

;   mov cx,0B000H
;   test byte es:0x0410,2
;   jnz .Address_OK

;   mov cx,0B800H

;.Address_OK:
;   mov es,cx
;   mov al,'H'

;   mov es:[si],byte al

;   mov es:0,byte al

;   mov es:si,byte al
;   mov ds:si,byte al
;   mov ds:[si],byte al
;   inc si
;   ret

;use16
;[bits 16]
;task_poke16:
;   mov dword [tss.eip],ecx
;   mov dword [tss.eflags]

;   mov ax,[tss.eax]
;   mov cx,[tss.ecx]
;   mov dx,[tss.edx]
;   mov bx,[tss.ebx]
;   mov sp,[tss.esp]
;   mov bp,[tss.ebp]
;   mov si,[tss.esi]
;   mov di,[tss.type2]

;   mov cx,[tss.ds]
;   mov es,cx
;   mov ss,cx
;   mov ds,cx
;   mov fs,cx
;   mov gs,cx
```

boot.asm

```
;    ReTimerOS
;    Copyright (C) 2022,2023  Christopher Hoy
;
;    This file is part of ReTimerOS
;    ReTimerOS is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
;    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
;    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
;    (at your option) any later version.
;
;    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
;    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
;    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
;    GNU General Public License for more details.
;
;    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
;    along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.


[BITS 16]
;[ORG 0x7c00]


section .text

_prep_module:
    xor ax,ax   
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax  
    mov ss,ax
;    mov sp,0x7c00
    mov sp,0x9000

DriveIdPrep:
    mov [DriveId],dl
    mov ah,0x41
    mov bx,0x55aa
    int 0x13
;    jc CheckPrep
    cmp bx,0xaa55
;    jne CheckPrep

SizeFunction:
    mov bx,0x0000_7E00
    mov cl,2
    mov ah,0x02
;   mov al,1
    mov al,5
    mov ch,0
    mov dh,0
    int 0x13
;    jc  ReadCheck

    mov dl,[DriveId]

;   mov si,[String1]

    jmp 0x7e00 

;   call prototype3
;   call main
;   jmp $





Section .data  
DriveId:    db 0
String:    db "Check",0
MessageLen: equ $-String
ReadPacket: times 16 db 0
ColorTable: db 00h,01h,02h,03h,04h,05h,06h,07h
            ;db 10h,11h,12h,13h,14h,15h,16h,17h
            db 38h,39h,3Ah,3Bh,3Ch,3Dh,3Eh,3Fh
ColorTableSize: equ $-ColorTable



ROWS    EQU 25
COLS1   EQU 80
BACK1   EQU 05h
FRONT1  EQU 12h
CHECKER EQU 0

;Graphics_CTRLA EQU 0x03CE
;Sequencer_CTRLA    EQU 0x03C4
Graphics_CTRLA  EQU 03CEh
Sequencer_CTRLA EQU 03C4h
Crd1Size        EQU 640
HDATA           EQU (Crd1Size/8)
Graph_Segment   EQU 0A000H
;HDATA          EQU (crd2+crd1/8)
;Crd1   EQU [bp+4]
;Crd2   EQU [bp+6]
;Color  EQU [bp+8]
crd1    EQU 45
crd2    EQU 54
color   EQU 05h




X dd 0
Y dd 0
color_pkg dw 0x05

LoopVar1:   db 0

;LoopVar    EQU [LoopVar1]

;ROWS   EQU 0x18
;COLS1  EQU 0x4F

;ROWS:  db 20
;COLS1: db 80

Value1:     db 0
```

Makefile```

```
FILES =boot.o printstr.o
PROCURE = rm -rf

all:    boot.bin stage1.bin
    dd if=boot.bin of=os.img bs=512 count=1 conv=notrunc
    dd if=stage1.bin of=os.img bs=512 count=3 seek=1 conv=notrunc

boot.o: boot.asm
    nasm -f elf -g -o boot.o boot.asm

printstr.o: printstr.asm
    nasm -f elf -g -o printstr.o printstr.asm

stage1.o: stage1.asm
    nasm -f elf -g stage1.asm -o stage1.o


boot.bin: $(FILES)
    ld -T link.ld $(FILES) -o boot.bin

stage1.bin: stage1.o
    ld -g -m elf_i386 -T link2.ld stage1.o -o stage1.bin --oformat binary


clean:
    $(PROCURE) */.o
    $(PROCURE) */.bin
    $(PROCURE) os.img
```

``

printstr.asm

```
bits 16


global printstr

printstr:

lodsb
test al,al
jz .done
mov ah,0x0E
mov bx,7
int 0x10
jmp printstr

.done: 
    ret
```

Cheers!

Revision 1

From our diligent community forum's contribution and the tinkering from the previous link I'm happy to respond that I got a good model for the main BIOS task method as a call back by first going through the protected gate path first. The good news is the code runs completely however I'm getting a stall from the int 16 keyboard function that I'm now having to test.

```
Here is the new version of the stage1.asm

;    ReTimerOS
;    Copyright (C) 2022,2023  Christopher Hoy
;
;    This file is part of ReTimerOS
;    ReTimerOS is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
;    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
;    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
;    (at your option) any later version.
;
;    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
;    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
;    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
;    GNU General Public License for more details.
;
;    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
;    along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.


;[ORG 0x7E00]

%define BUILD_GDT_DESC(bounds,base,access,flags) \
((( base & 0x00FFFFFF) << 16) | \
(( base & 0xFF000000) << 32) | \
( bounds & 0x0000FFFF) |        \
(( bounds & 0x000F0000) << 32) | \
(( access & 0xFF) << 40) |      \
(( flags & 0x0F) << 52))        

TSS_IO_MAP_SIZE     EQU 0x400/8


%define REBASE_ADDRESS(A)  (0x7E00 + ((A) - _prep_module2))

[BITS 16]


section .text

_prep_module2:
    jmp protectedGate1



[bits 32]
BIOS32_PREP:use32
    pusha
    ;pushf
    mov edx, esp
    ; jumping to 16 bit protected mode
    ; disable interrupts
    cli
    ; clear cr3 by saving cr3 data in ebx register
    xor ecx, ecx
    mov ebx, cr3
    mov cr3, ecx

    ; load new empty GDT
;   lgdt [REBASE_ADDRESS(bios32_gdt_ptr)]
;    lgdt [REBASE_ADDRESS(gdt32Ptr)]

    ; load new empty IDT
;   lidt [REBASE_ADDRESS(bios32_idt_ptr)]

    ; jump to 16 bit protected mode

   
;    jmp 0x30:REBASE_ADDRESS(__protected_mode_16)
;    jmp 0x30:__protected_mode_16
;    jmp 0x0:REBASE_ADDRESS(__protected_mode_16)        
;   jmp 0:__protected_mode_16


    jmp code16_post:REBASE_ADDRESS(__protected_mode_16)
;   jmp code16_post:__protected_mode_16


[bits 16]
; 16 bit protected mode
__protected_mode_16:use16
    ; jumping to 16 bit real mode
    mov eax,cr0
    mov [save_cr0],eax
    and eax,07ffffffeh
    mov cr0,eax


    xor eax,eax
    xor ecx,ecx
    mov ax,data16_post

    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax
    ; turn off protected mode
    ; set bit 0 to 0
    mov eax, cr0
    and al,  ~0x01
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp 0x0:REBASE_ADDRESS(__real_mode_16)

;[bits 16]
__real_mode_16:use16
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x8c00
    ; enable bios interrupts to call
    sti

    pusha
    mov cx, ss
    push cx
    mov cx, gs
    push cx
    mov cx, fs
    push cx
    mov cx, es
    push cx
    mov cx, ds
    push cx
    pushf
    ; get current stack pointer & save it to current_esp
    mov ax, sp
;    mov edi, current_esp
    mov di, current_esp

    stosw
    ; load our custom registers context
    mov esp, REBASE_ADDRESS(bios32_in_reg16_ptr)
;    mov sp, REBASE_ADDRESS(bios32_in_reg16_ptr)

    ; only use some general register from the given context
    popa
    ; set a new stack for bios interrupt
    mov sp, 0x9c00
    ; call immediate interrupt opcode to execute context

    pusha
;   mov bp,sp
;   mov word [saved_stack],sp   


;   mov dx,sp 
;   jmp GraphicCtrlA
;   jmp bios32_GraphicCtrlA



bios32_GraphicCtrlA:use16

; will be bios interrupt number passed
    ; put the actual interrupt number here
;   db 0xCD
;    db 0x10
;   db 0x01

    mov ax,0x13
    
    int 0x10

    mov dh,1
    mov dl,1
    call GraphicPrint


;   popa
;   jmp poll_function


loopstep1:use16
    
    mov ah,01h
    int 16h
    jz loopstep1

    call GraphicPrint



;Set:
    mov ah,00h
    int 16h

    cmp ah,48h
    jnz .SetOn
    
    cmp dl,0
    jz .SetOn
    dec dl

.SetOn:

    cmp ah,50h
    jnz .SetOff
    cmp dl,24
    jz .SetOff
    inc dl

.SetOff:

    cmp ah,0x4B
;ratchet test complete !

    jne .SetNotLeft

    cmp dh,0
    je .SetNotLeft

    dec dh  

.SetNotLeft:

    cmp ah,0x4D
    jnz .SetNotRight
    cmp dh,39
    jz .SetNotRight

    inc dh  

.SetNotRight:

    call GraphicPrint
    jmp loopstep1


GraphicPrint:
    mov cx,0A000h
    mov es,cx

    push dx

    mov ax,8
    mul dh
    mov bp,ax

    mov ax,8*320
    mov bx,0
    add bl,dl
    mul bx
    add bp,ax

    pop dx

    mov si,GraphicA
    mov cl,8
    
PrintGraphicY:
    push bp

    mov ch,8

PrintGraphicX:
    mov al,[ds:si]
    xor al,[es:bp]
    mov [es:bp],al
    inc si
    inc bp
    dec ch
    jnz PrintGraphicX

    pop bp
    add bp,320
    dec cl
    jnz PrintGraphicY

;   hlt
    ret


GraphicA:
    db 00h,00h,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,00h,00h  
    db 00h,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,00h
    db 0Eh,0Eh,05h,0Eh,0Eh,05h,0Eh,0Eh
    db 0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh
    db 0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh
    db 0Eh,0Eh,04h,0Eh,0Eh,04h,0Eh,0Eh
    db 00h,0Eh,0Eh,04h,04h,0Eh,0Eh,00h
    db 00h,00h,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,0Eh,00h,00h




poll_function:
;   popa
    ; get our output context here
    mov esp, REBASE_ADDRESS(bios32_out_reg16_ptr)

    add sp, 28 ; restore stack used for calling our context
    ; save current context, all general, segment registers, flags
    pushf
    mov cx, ss
    push cx
    mov cx, gs
    push cx
    mov cx, fs
    push cx
    mov cx, es
    push cx
    mov cx, ds
    push cx
    pusha
    ; restate the current_esp to continue
    mov esi, current_esp

    lodsw
    mov sp, ax
    ; restore all current context, all general, segment registers, flags
    popf
    pop cx
    mov ds, cx
    pop cx
    mov es, cx
    pop cx
    mov fs, cx
    pop cx
    mov gs, cx
    pop cx
    mov ss, cx
    popa
    
[bits 16]
protectedGate1:
    cld
    cli

    in al,0x92
    or al,2
    out 0x92,al

    lgdt[gdt32Ptr]
    lidt[IdtPipe]

    mov eax, cr0
    or eax,1
    mov cr0, eax

    jmp code32_post:__protected_mode_32



__padding:
    db 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 0x0
bios32_gdt_entries:
    ; 8 gdt entries
    resb 64
bios32_gdt_ptr:
    dd 0x00000000
    dd 0x00000000
bios32_idt_ptr:
    dd 0x00000000
    dd 0x00000000
bios32_in_reg16_ptr:
    resw 14
bios32_out_reg16_ptr:
    dd 0xaaaaaaaa
    dd 0xaaaaaaaa
    dd 0xaaaaaaaa
    dd 0xaaaaaaaa
    dd 0xaaaaaaaa
    dd 0xaaaaaaaa
    dd 0xaaaaaaaa
current_esp:
    dw 0x0000




[bits 32]
; 32 bit protected mode
__protected_mode_32:use32
;    mov ax, 0x10
    mov ax,data32_post
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
;    mov ss, ax
    ; restore cr3
    mov cr3, ebx
    ; restore esp
    mov esp, edx

;    sti
;    popa

;   hlt

;   jmp _BIOS32_PREP
;   jmp code16_post:REBASE_ADDRESS(__protected_mode_32)
;   jmp code16_post:REBASE_ADDRESS(BIOS32_PREP)
;   jmp code16_post:REBASE_ADDRESS(BIOS32_PREP)

    jmp code32_post:REBASE_ADDRESS(BIOS32_PREP)


;use16
;   jmp code16_post:REBASE_ADDRESS(BIOS32_PREP)

;    lgdt [REBASE_ADDRESS(bios32_gdt_ptr)]

 ;   jmp 0x30:REBASE_ADDRESS(__protected_mode_16)

    jmp $

    
.loopcheck:
    hlt
    jmp .loopcheck




section .data 

gdt32:
    dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(0,0,0,0)
gdt32code:
    dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(0x0000ffff,0,10011010b,1100b)
gdt32data:
    dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(0x0000ffff,0,10010010b,1100b)
gdt16code:
    dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(0x0000ffff,0,10011010b,1000b)
gdt16data:
    dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(0x0000ffff,0,10010010b,1000b)

    ;gdt16tss:dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(0x8230,TSS_SIZE-1,10001001b,0000b) & 0 << 22
gdt32tss:
    dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(TSS_SIZE-1,0x8280,10001001b,0000b)
;   dq BUILD_GDT_DESC(TSS_SIZE-1,0x9260,10001001b,0000b)    
.stub1:

    code32_post: equ gdt32code -gdt32
    data32_post: equ gdt32data -gdt32
;.stub:
    code16_post: equ gdt16code -gdt32
    data16_post: equ gdt16data -gdt32

    tss32_post: equ gdt32tss -gdt32
    
    gdt32Len: equ $-gdt32   
    gdt32Ptr: dw gdt32Len-1
        dd gdt32


align 4
;vidmem_ptr: dd VIDEO_TEXT_ADDR
pm_str: db 'protected mode string ',0
pm_str_length: equ $-pm_str
vm_str: db 'virtual',0
;vidmem_address: dw 0

;resb 512
times 512 db 0

align 16
tss:
.back_link:     dd 0
.esp0:          dd 0
.ss0:           dd 0
.esp1:          dd 0
.ss1:           dd 0
.esp2:          dd 0
.ss2:           dd 0
.cr3:           dd 0
.eip:           dd 0
.eflags:        dd 0
.eax:           dd 0
.ecx:           dd 0
.edx:           dd 0
.ebx:           dd 0
.esp:           dd 0
.ebp:           dd 0
.esi:           dd 0
.type2:         dd 0
.es:            dd 0
.cs:            dd 0
.ss:            dd 0
.ds:            dd 0
.fs:            dd 0
.gs:            dd 0
.ldt:           dd 0
.trap:          dw 0
.iomap_base:    dw 0

.iomap: TIMES TSS_IO_MAP_SIZE db 0x00

%if TSS_IO_MAP_SIZE > 0
.iomap_pad:db 0xff

%endif
.end:
TSS_SIZE: EQU tss.end -tss

align 4

ColorTable: db 00h,01h,02h,03h,04h,05h,06h,07h
            ;db 10h,11h,12h,13h,14h,15h,16h,17h
            db 38h,39h,3Ah,3Bh,3Ch,3Dh,3Eh,3Fh
ColorTableSize: equ $-ColorTable

save_cr0    dd 0
save_cr3    dd 0
saved_segment   resd 0
gate_voucher    dw 1
saved_stack resw 0


ROWS    EQU 25
COLS1   EQU 80

IdtPipe:
    dw 0x03ff
    dd 0

;X  dd 0
;Y   dd 0
;color_pkg  dw 5

section .bss
align 16 
;ring0_proc_stack: resb RING0_PROC_STACK_SIZE
ring0_proc_stack_placer:

align 4
save_esp:   resd 1
save_ss:    resd 1
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are showing us the code you are ACTUALLY using and running? Again, this code makes NO sense. Before even trying to understand your problem, I'm actually still trying to understand the very basic part of the code. Your bootloader jumps to stage1 while in real mode. The code then starts executing at 0x7e00. While in real mode you have `use32` at label `BIOS32_PREP`. Everything from that point until the next `use` directive will encode 32-bit instructions but you are running in 16-bit real mode.

Comment: As a result the 32-bit LGDT encoding run in 16-bit real mode actually loads the GDT from the wrong place in memory then executes a bunch of instructions that are not what you want (and doesn't even do an LIDT). By sheer luck though the `jmp 0x30:REBASE_ADDRESS(__protected_mode_16)` ends up getting executed as `jmp 0x0000:__protected_mode_16`  which ends up jumping to label __protected_mode_16 while in real mode still. The only way the code at BIOS32_PREP would work is if you are already in 32-bit protected mode but the code you show never enters 32-bit protected mode first

Comment: From this one respone I managed to get a good yield by re-ordering the code to move through the protected Gate first and calling back into BIOS32. While this is the most likely outcome for BIOS taskings the one other hiccup is now I have a stall in the int 16h keyboard instruction. I'll be posting the code revision now and I appreciate the your keen contributions here!

Comment: Yeah I tried another set video 0x13 to check the stall but while that's good my keyboard controller is still stalling

Comment: At least with the code posted here (and the link.ld and link2.ld from the previous answer) I was unable to get it to stall at all. Does the version you posted here (as is) stall or not? If it does is there something special you do? What environment are you running it in/on? Real hardware? Bochs? QEMU? Something else? If you are running different version of the code that you posted that doesn't work can you add it as a an edit to the question so that we ight be able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: The only other thing I use for this program is a simple Qemu call (qemu-system-i386 os.img)

Comment: That's why I didn't see the keyboard not working. I was running it with `qemu-system-i386 -fda os.img` (no keyboard stall) and you ran it with `qemu-system-i386 os.img` (which is the same as `qemu-system-i386 -hda os.img`. Its an unusual problem but difficult to pin down because the code you have is sort of all over the place and finding the problem is more complex than I expected. There has got to be a bug in there. I know the issue isn't in the bootloader. I suspect it has to do with the hard drive access doing something different (Diff IRQ etc) that brings about this bug.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here. To call 16-bit code after entering 32-bit protected mode and then return back to 32-bit protected mode? I ask this question because if I knew what the actual goal was I could probably recode it from scratch.

Comment: Uhm yeah if I were to restate that I'd say a simple BIOS task to call BIOS 16 code from standard 32

Comment: When you say a "task" do you mean a hardware task, or just a mechanism (function) that can go from 32-bit mode down to real mode to call 16-bit real mode code and then come back to 32-bit protected mode. I mention hardware tasks because at one point I think some of your code suggested you were trying that as well. From some of your code it seems you also want to past some type of register context.